# WSO2 ESB: SFTP file transfer: Could not connect to SFTP server

Tags: wso2, sftp, wso2-esb

I am trying to transfer some files from local server to SFTP server using WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 6.3.0. I have username, SFTP location, SFTP port(990), ppk file and PassPhrase. When I tried below configuration in my Proxy service, I couldn't connect to SFTP server. It gives com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail error. With putty, connection works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="SFTPFileTransferProxy" startOnLoad="true"
  trace="disable" transports="vfs" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <target>
    <inSequence>
      <property expression="$trp:FILE_NAME" name="FILE_NAME"
        scope="default" type="STRING"/>
      <log level="custom">
        <property expression="$ctx:FILE_NAME" name="FL2"/>
        <property name="sequence" value="FTPProxy"/>
      </log>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence/>
    <faultSequence/>
  </target>
  <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">10000ms</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">file:///C:/files/out</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">file:///C:/test/failure</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.SFTPIdentities">file:///C:/sftp/keys/PrivateKey_Integration.ppk</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*\.csv</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">vfs:sftp://username@sftp.XXXX.com:990/in/file/</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.vfs.SFTPIdentityPassPhrase">KEY_PASSPHRASE</parameter>
</proxy>
```

And the error I am getting is

```
[2019-02-04 12:48:31,823] [] ERROR - VFSTransportListener File object 'file:///C:/files/out/20181226FULL.csv'cloud not be moved, will remain in "locked" state
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error resolving directory to move after processing : sftp://username@sftp.XXXX.com:990/in/file
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractTransportListener.handleException(AbstractTransportListener.java:343)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.moveOrDeleteAfterProcessing(VFSTransportListener.java:715)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.scanFileOrDirectory(VFSTransportListener.java:504)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.poll(VFSTransportListener.java:188)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.poll(VFSTransportListener.java:134)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractPollingTransportListener$1$1.run(AbstractPollingTransportListener.java:67)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not connect to SFTP server at "sftp://username@sftp.XXXX.com:990/".
        at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpFileProvider.doCreateFileSystem(SftpFileProvider.java:86)
        at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.getFileSystem(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:149)
        at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.findFile(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:111)
        at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.findFile(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:81)
        at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileSystemManager.resolveFile(DefaultFileSystemManager.java:778)
        at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileSystemManager.resolveFile(DefaultFileSystemManager.java:658)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.moveOrDeleteAfterProcessing(VFSTransportListener.java:667)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not connect to SFTP server at "sftp.XXXX.com".
        at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory.createConnection(SftpClientFactory.java:164)
        at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpFileProvider.doCreateFileSystem(SftpFileProvider.java:79)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:519)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
        at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory.createConnection(SftpClientFactory.java:162)
        ... 15 more
```

How to connect SFTP server with SFTPIdentities?

Comment: PPK files are specific to putty. Did you try to convert it to regular ssh keys ?

Comment: Yes. I tried that too. But same error.

Comment: Just  to make sure: You're trying to use inbound SFTP, right ? Another thing: try using the transport.vfs.SFTPUserDirIsRoot=true parameter to see if there's any change. Last, please add the full stack trace in the message, as it sometimes can help to point to the problem's source.

Comment: Updated the question with Proxy file details and error stack.

Comment: Just to help isolating the root cause, can you change the ActionAfterProcess parameter to "NONE" ?

Comment: It gives me error "[2019-02-05 12:22:54,189] [] ERROR - ClientUtils Address information does not exist in the Endpoint Reference (EPR).The system cannot infer the transport mechanism.
[2019-02-05 12:22:54,189] [] ERROR - Axis2Sender Unexpected error during sending message out
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Address information does not exist in the Endpoint Reference (EPR).The system cannot infer the transport mechanism."

Comment: Well, that makes sense. The proxy has no endpoint, so the ESB gets confused since it has no idea what to do with the message. Now try adding send mediator with a VFS endpoint, such as:
<log level="full"/>
<send>
<endpoint>
<address uri="vfs:sftp://username@sftp.XXXX.com:990/in/file/"/>
</endpoint>
</send>

Comment: Same error. Auth fails even after adding endpoint to outbound.

Answer (score 1):

Try Key path as below, on Windows. It works for me.

```
<parameter name="transport.vfs.SFTPIdentities">/sftp/keys/PrivateKey_Integration.ppk</parameter>
```

On Ubuntu, I am giving the key path as

```
<parameter name="transport.vfs.SFTPIdentities">/home/sbhatti/.ssh/key.ppk</parameter>
```

But it is not working, and giving the same exception as posted in question above. anyone has any idea? How we can debug and apply correct path?

Comment: @PhilippeSevestre I have applied ActionAfterProcess parameter to "NONE". It does not give any error and ends successfully. What does this implies?

Comment: Hi @NGR,
I am facing "Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not connect to SFTP server at "server Ip"", tried with VFS, FileInbound and FileConnector, Can u get any solution regards this?